# Python requests - correct way to send query-string for POST

Tags: python, python-requests, query-string, urlencode

Here is what I want to be sent:

```
https://dev.xxx.com/employee-service/login?email=apitester@xxx.com&password=xxx!xxx

Body:
{
<JSON>
}
```

Here is how I send it.

###### Why I didn't use a dictionary for params

Because when I did, the @ in the email and the ! in the password got encoded.

```
    params = 'email=' + l_email + '&password=' + l_password
    l_response = requests.post(url=url, data=params, json=body, headers={'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}, verify=False)
```

What I got

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-05-16T12:20:56.918+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "errors": [
        {
            "codes": [
                "NotEmpty.systemUserLogin.password",
                "NotEmpty.password",
                "NotEmpty.java.lang.String",
                "NotEmpty"
            ],
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "codes": [
                        "systemUserLogin.password",
                        "password"
                    ],
                    "arguments": null,
                    "defaultMessage": "password",
                    "code": "password"
                }
            ],
            "defaultMessage": "must not be empty",
            "objectName": "systemUserLogin",
            "field": "password",
            "rejectedValue": null,
            "bindingFailure": false,
            "code": "NotEmpty"
        },
        {
            "codes": [
                "NotNull.systemUserLogin.password",
                "NotNull.password",
                "NotNull.java.lang.String",
                "NotNull"
            ],
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "codes": [
                        "systemUserLogin.password",
                        "password"
                    ],
                    "arguments": null,
                    "defaultMessage": "password",
                    "code": "password"
                }
            ],
            "defaultMessage": "must not be null",
            "objectName": "systemUserLogin",
            "field": "password",
            "rejectedValue": null,
            "bindingFailure": false,
            "code": "NotNull"
        },
        {
            "codes": [
                "NotNull.systemUserLogin.email",
                "NotNull.email",
                "NotNull.java.lang.String",
                "NotNull"
            ],
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "codes": [
                        "systemUserLogin.email",
                        "email"
                    ],
                    "arguments": null,
                    "defaultMessage": "email",
                    "code": "email"
                }
            ],
            "defaultMessage": "must not be null",
            "objectName": "systemUserLogin",
            "field": "email",
            "rejectedValue": null,
            "bindingFailure": false,
            "code": "NotNull"
        },
        {
            "codes": [
                "NotEmpty.systemUserLogin.email",
                "NotEmpty.email",
                "NotEmpty.java.lang.String",
                "NotEmpty"
            ],
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "codes": [
                        "systemUserLogin.email",
                        "email"
                    ],
                    "arguments": null,
                    "defaultMessage": "email",
                    "code": "email"
                }
            ],
            "defaultMessage": "must not be empty",
            "objectName": "systemUserLogin",
            "field": "email",
            "rejectedValue": null,
            "bindingFailure": false,
            "code": "NotEmpty"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Validation failed for object='systemUserLogin'. Error count: 4",
    "path": "/employee-service/login"
}
```

How can I fully debug what *really* got sent?

What I did find was:

```
l_response.request.body

# email=apitester@xxx.com&password=xxx!xxx
```

My conclusion is that I am definitely **not** sending the query-string correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

###### What else I tried

It goes all wrong if I set the `url` argument to `https://dev.xxx.com/employee-service/login?email=apitester@xxx.com&password=xxx!xxx`: many errors, re-tries, SSL exceptions, etc.

Comment: What I didn't understand: Do you want to send your POST data as JSON?
In this case you would send the request like this:
l_response = requests.post(url=url, data=json.dumps(YOUR_DICT), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, verify=False)

Otherwise, the format with the parameters separated by an ampersand is of Content-Type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".
So perhaps your use of "text/plain" is wrong?

Comment: Here is something that did work:  `    #  data={'locationId': location_id}
    l_response = s.post(url=url+'?locationId=110', json=user_json, verify=False,
                        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})`   I don't like it, though, because your supposed to use a  `dict` argument for the `data`.     But it nevertheless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, this worked.

I will close this item.

```
l_response = s.post(url=url+'?locationId=110', json=user_json, verify=False, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```